# Disable path user on Drupal 7

Tags: users

Since most of my d7 users will authenticate somewhere outside Drupal itself, I need to disable "/user" path for most of them (not uid 0 of course).
What is the best approach we have here?

Comment: Do you wants to disable "/user" link for all users without admin?

Comment: How exactly will the site be able to identify who the user is so that it disables the '/user' path without the user being already authenticated I wonder. Also to ask why.

Comment: @Smalution : I'd prefer to be flexible here (let me handle who is allowed)

Comment: @Wtower :  users will authenticate somewhere outside Drupal itself, so no need for them to cahge pwd, username etc

Comment: Do you think its due to spamming?

Comment: How user is being authenticated from external url. And what are the param that is passed to drupal to login

Comment: @Raj10 : there's a3rd party api call. out of scope, btw

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
function mymenu_menu_alter(&$items) {
$global $user;
 if ($user->uid != '0'){
  $items['user']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid mymenu_menu_alter(&$items) is cached

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions is fine and work correctly,but if you want do it with modules feature you can try redirect it with [Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect), install it, then redirect every `user` and `user/*`  path to `/`(or any path you want).

Comment: + keep the login in a block and put it on a specific page to keep a login access for the userone only.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the access to this path:

```
function mymenu_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: This won't let me allow user->uid[0]

Comment: You can test if current user uid is 0. Or you can set an access callback permission like this: `$items['user']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_access_user_path';` and then create the function: `function mymodule_access_user_path() {
  global $user;
  if(in_array('admin', array_values($user->roles)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}`

Answer (score 0):

My best bet so far is:

```
function MYMODULE_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode)  {
  global $user ;
  if ($user->uid > 1) {
    drupal_goto ("");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be like this (in template.php) :

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
  if ($variables['user']->uid > 1 && arg(0) == 'user') {
    drupal_goto('SOME_PATH'); // instead of restricting the access
  }
}
```